# DF function doesn't work for implementation of F distribution using R and Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

i have a project for my class to implement 15 distribution. All good but i can't figure out for 2 distributions, F and Uniform.

So, for my F distribution, when i use DF function i get that error saying i there are unused parameters and i don't really now why. (checked on google how to use it and it doesn't work).

And for the Uniform distribution, for the first graph I need ylim to be finite, which i pretty done but again, idk why it doesn't work. And for the probability calculation idk why I get that error, checked on google before coming here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m30l9.png)

This is the error for F function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyfVC.png)

And this is the error for the Uniform function.

Here is the code i used:

```
ui<-fluidPage(
fluidRow(
  column(2,
    selectInput("dist","Choose the probability distribution: ", choices =
                list(Continuous = list("Normal",
                                       "Beta",
                                       "Chi-squared",
                                       "Exponential",
                                       "F",
                                       "Cauchy",
                                       "Logistic",
                                       "StudentT",
                                       "Uniform",
                                       "Gamma",
                                       "Lognormal",
                                       "Weibull"),
                     Discrete = list("Binomial",
                                     "Poisson",
                                     "Geometric")))),
column(2,
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Normal'",
         numericInput("mean", "Mean: ", value = 0),
         numericInput("sd", "Standard deviation: ", value = 1, min=0)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Chi-squared'",
         numericInput("df", "Degrees of freedom: ", value = 1, min = 2, step = 1)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Beta'",
         numericInput("alfa","Alpha: ", value = 1,min=1),
         numericInput("beta", "Beta: ", value = 1,min=1)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Poisson'",
         numericInput("lambda","Lambda: ", value = 1,min = 0)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Binomial'",
         numericInput("n","n: ", value = 10,step=1),
         numericInput("p", "p: ", value = 0,step=0.1,max=1,min=0)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Exponential'",
         numericInput("nExp","Rate: ",value = 1, min=0)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'F'",
         numericInput("f1","F1: ", value = 1),
         numericInput("f2","F2: ", value = 1)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Logistic'",
         numericInput("log","Logistic: ", value = 1),
         numericInput("scale","Scale: ", value = 1)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'StudentT'",
         numericInput("v","StudentT: ",value = 1, min=1)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Uniform'",
         numericInput("u1","Val1: ", value = 1),
         numericInput("u2","Val2: ", value = 1)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Cauchy'",
         numericInput("location", "Location: ", value = 0),
         numericInput("cscale", "Scale: ", value = 1, min=1)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Gamma'",
         numericInput("rate", "Rate: ", value = 1, min=1),
         numericInput("gshape", "Shape: ", value = 1, min=0),
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Lognormal'",
         numericInput("meanlog", "Mean: ", value = 0),
         numericInput("sdlog", "Standard deviation: ", value = 0.05, min=0.05, step=0.05)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Weibull'",
         numericInput("wscale", "Scale: ", value = 1, min=0),
         numericInput("wshape", "Shape: ", value = 1, min=0)
       ),
       conditionalPanel(
         condition = "input.dist == 'Geometric'",
         numericInput("prob", "Probability: ", value = 1, min=0, step=0.1, max=1)
       )
   )
 ),
fluidRow(
       column(6,
       plotOutput("densityPlot")
  ),
  column(6,
       plotOutput("cdfPlot")
  )
  ),
fluidRow(
       column(2,
       selectInput("probType", "Choose type of probability", 
                 choices = list("P(X<=a)", "P(X>=a)", "P(a<=X<=b)"))
   ),
   column(2,
     conditionalPanel(
       condition = "input.probType == 'P(X<=a)'",
       numericInput("a", "a:", value=0)
     ),
     conditionalPanel(
       condition = "input.probType == 'P(X>=a)'",
       numericInput("b", "a:", value=0)
     ),
     conditionalPanel(
       condition = "input.probType == 'P(a<=X<=b)'",
       numericInput("aa", "a:", value=0),
       numericInput("bb", "b:", value=0)
     )           
  ),
  column(6,
       textOutput("result"),
       plotOutput("resultPlot"))
 )
)
server<-function(input, output, session) {
dist<-reactive(input$dist)

a<-reactive(input$a)
b<-reactive(input$b)
aa<-reactive(input$aa)
bb<-reactive(input$bb)
probType<-reactive(input$probType)

# Distribution specific vars
# Normal
nMean<-reactive(input$mean)
sd<-reactive(input$sd)

# Poisson
lambda<-reactive(input$lambda)

# Binomial
n<-reactive(input$n)
p<-reactive(input$p)

# Beta
alfa<-reactive(input$alfa)
beta<-reactive(input$beta)

# Chi-squared
df<-reactive(input$df)

# Exponential
nExp<-reactive(input$nExp)

#F
f1<-reactive(input$f1)
f2<-reactive(input$f2)

#Logistic
log<-reactive(input$log)
scale<-reactive(input$scale)

#StudentT
v<-reactive(input$v)

#Uniform
u1<-reactive(input$u1)
u2<-reactive(input$u2)

# Cauchy
location<-reactive(input$location)
cscale<-reactive(input$cscale)

#Gamma
rate<-reactive(input$rate)
gshape<-reactive(input$gshape)

#Geometric
prob<-reactive(input$prob)

#Lognormal
meanlog<-reactive(input$meanlog)
sdlog<-reactive(input$sdlog)

#Weibull
wscale<-reactive(input$wscale)
wshape<-reactive(input$wshape)

# Reactive vars to calculate properties of dist
inf<-reactive({
 switch(dist(),
       "Normal"=nMean()-3*sd(),
       "Beta"=0,
       "Poisson"=0,
       "Binomial"=0,
       "Chi-squared"=0,
       "Exponential"=0,
       "F"=0,
       "Logistic"=-2*log(),
       "StudentT"=-10,
       "Uniform"=-5*u1(),
       "Cauchy"=(-1)*abs(3*location()) + location(),
       "Gamma"=0,
       "Geometric"=0,
       "Lognormal"=0,
       "Weibull"=0)
})

sup<-reactive({
switch(dist(),
       "Normal"=nMean()+3*sd(),
       "Beta"=1,
       "Poisson"=2*lambda(),
       "Binomial"=n(),
       "Chi-squared"=df()*2,
       "Exponential"= 2**(nExp()),
       "F"=f1()+f2(),
       "Logistic"=10*log(),
       "StudentT"=10,
       "Uniform"=5*u2(),
       "Cauchy"=abs(3*location()) + location(),
       "Gamma"=2*gshape(),
       "Geometric"=20,
       "Lognormal"=20,
       "Weibull"=wscale()*2)
}) 

points<-reactive({
switch(dist(),
       "Normal"=seq(from=inf(),to=sup(),length.out=1000),
       "Beta"=seq(from=inf(),to=sup(),length.out=1000),
       "Poisson"=inf():sup(),
       "Binomial"=inf():sup(), 
       "Chi-squared"=seq(from=inf(),to=sup(),length.out=1000),
       "Exponential"=seq(from=inf(),to=sup(),length.out=1000),
       "F"=seq(from=inf(),to=sup(),length.out=1000),
       "Logistic"=seq(from=inf(),to=sup(),length.out=1000),
       "StudentT"=seq(from=inf(),to=sup(),length.out=1000),
       "Uniform"==seq(from=inf(),to=sup(),length.out=1000),
       # location=0 then inf=sup=0 
       "Cauchy"=seq(from=if(inf()==0) -5 else inf(),to=if(sup()==0) 5 else 
 sup(),length.out=1000),
       "Gamma"=seq(from=inf(),to=sup(),length.out=1000),
       "Geometric"=inf():sup(),
       "Lognormal"=seq(from=inf(),to=sup(),length.out=1000),
       "Weibull"=seq(from=inf(),to=sup(),length.out=1000))
 })

 density<-reactive({
     switch(dist(),
       "Normal"=dnorm(points(),nMean(),sd()),
       "Beta"=dbeta(points(),alfa(),beta()),
       "Poisson"=dpois(points(),lambda()),
       "Binomial"=dbinom(points(),n(),p()),
       "Chi-squared"=dchisq(points(),df()),
       "Exponential"=dexp(points(), nExp()),
       "F"= df(points(), f1(),f2()),
       "Logistic"=dlogis(points(), log(), scale()),
       "StudentT"=dt(points(), v()),
       "Uniform"=dunif(points(), u1(), u2()),
       "Cauchy"=dcauchy(points(),location(),cscale()),
       "Gamma"=dgamma(points(),gshape(),rate()),
       "Geometric"=dgeom(points(),prob()),
       "Lognormal"=dlnorm(points(),meanlog(),sdlog()),
       "Weibull"=dweibull(points(),wshape(),wscale()))
 })

 cdf<-reactive({
   switch(dist(),
       "Normal"=pnorm(points(),nMean(),sd()),
       "Beta"=pbeta(points(),alfa(),beta()),
       "Poisson"=ppois(points(),lambda()),
       "Binomial"=pbinom(points(),n(),p()),
       "Chi-squared"=pchisq(points(),df()),
       "Exponential"=pexp(points(),nExp()),
       "F"=pf(points(), f1(),f2()),
       "Logistic"=plogis(points(), log(), scale()),
       "StudentT"=pt(points(), v()),
       "Uniform"=punif(points(), u1(), u2()),
       "Cauchy"=pcauchy(points(),location(),cscale()),
       "Gamma"=pgamma(points(),gshape(),rate()),
       "Geometric"=pgeom(points(),prob()),
       "Lognormal"=plnorm(points(),meanlog(),sdlog()),
       "Weibull"=pweibull(points(),wshape(),wscale()))
  })

  mean<-reactive({
  switch(dist(),
       "Normal"=nMean(),
       "Beta"=alfa()/(alfa()+beta()),
       "Poisson"=lambda(),
       "Binomial" = n()*p(),
       "Chi-squared" = df(),
       "Exponential"= 1/nExp(),
       "F"=f2()/(f2()-2),
       "Logistic"=log(),
       "StudentT"=0,
       "Uniform"=(u1()+u2())/2,
       #"Cauchy"="undefined",
       "Gamma"=gshape()/rate(),
       "Geometric"=1/prob(),
       "Lognormal"=exp(meanlog() + 1/2 * sdlog()^2),
       "Weibull"=wscale() * gamma(1 + 1/wshape()))
  })

 cdfHelper<-function(x) {

   switch(dist(),
         "Normal"=pnorm(x,nMean(),sd()),
         "Beta"=pbeta(x,alfa(),beta()),
         "Poisson"=ppois(x,lambda()),
         "Binomial"=pbinom(x,n(),p()),
         "Chi-squared"=pchisq(x,df()),
         "Exponential"= pexp(x, nExp()),
         "F"= pf(x, f1(), f2()),
         "Logistic" = plogis(x, log(), scale()),
         "StudentT"= pt(x, v()),
         "Uniform"= punif(x, u1(), u2()),
         "Cauchy"=pcauchy(x,location(),cscale()),
         "Gamma"=pgamma(x,gshape(),rate()),
         "Geometric"=pgeom(x,prob()),
         "Lognormal"=plnorm(x,meanlog(),sdlog()),
         "Weibull"=pweibull(x,wshape(),wscale()))

  } 

  pdfHelper<-function(x) {

    switch(dist(),
         "Normal"=dnorm(x,nMean(),sd()),
         "Beta"=dbeta(x,alfa(),beta()),
         "Poisson"=dpois(x,lambda()),
         "Binomial"=dbinom(x,n(),p()),
         "Chi-squared"=dchisq(x,df()),
         "Exponential"=dexp(x, nExp()),
         "F"= df(x, f1(),f2()),
         "Logistic"=dlogis(x, log(), scale()),
         "StudentT"=dt(x, v()),
         "Uniform"=dunif(x, u1(), u2()),
         "Cauchy"=dcauchy(x,location(),cscale()),
         "Gamma"=dgamma(x,gshape(),rate()),
         "Geometric"=dgeom(x,prob()),
         "Lognormal"=dlnorm(x,meanlog(),sdlog()),
         "Weibull"=dweibull(x,wshape(),wscale()))

 } 

 output$densityPlot<-renderPlot({
  currDensity <- density()
  if (is.infinite(max(currDensity))) {
   yl<-c(0,4*5/3)
 } else {
   yl<-c(0,4*max(currDensity)/3)
 }

  plot(points(),currDensity,
     type="l",
     col = "cyan3",
     lwd=2.5,
     xlab="Values",
     ylab="PDF",
     main=dist(),
     ylim=yl)
 abline(v = mean(), col="cyan2",lwd = 2, lty = 2)
})

output$cdfPlot<-renderPlot({
  currCdf <- cdf()
  plot(points(),currCdf,
     type="l",
     col = "cyan3",
     lwd=2.5,
     xlab="Values",
     ylab="CDF",
     main=dist(),
     ylim = c(0,1))
})

output$result<-renderText({
  switch(probType(),
       'P(X<=a)' = cdfHelper(a()),
       'P(X>=a)' = 1 - cdfHelper(b()),
       'P(a<=X<=b)' = cdfHelper(bb()) - cdfHelper(aa())
       )
})

output$resultPlot<-renderPlot({
  currPoints<- points()
  currA<- a()
  currB<- b()
  currCdf<- cdf()
  switch(probType(),
       'P(X<=a)' = {
           plot(currPoints,currCdf,
                type="l",
                col = "cyan3",
                lwd=2.5,
                xlab="Values",
                ylab="CDF",
                main=dist(),
                ylim = c(0,1))
           polygon(c(currPoints[currPoints<=currA], currA),
                   c(currCdf[currPoints<=currA], currCdf[currPoints==min(currPoints)]),
                   col="cyan",
                   density=10,
                   angle=90)
         },
       'P(X>=a)' = {
         plot(currPoints,currCdf,
              type="l",
              col = "cyan3",
              lwd=2.5,
              xlab="Values",
              ylab="CDF",
              main=dist(),
              ylim = c(0,1))
         polygon(c(currPoints[currPoints>=currB], max(currPoints), currB),
                 c(currCdf[currPoints>=currB], 0, 0),
                 col="cyan",
                 density=10,
                 angle=90)
       },
       'P(a<=X<=b)' = {
         plot(currPoints,currCdf,
              type="l",
              col = "cyan3",
              lwd=2.5,
              xlab="Values",
              ylab="CDF",
              main=dist(),
              ylim = c(0,1))
         polygon(c(currPoints[currPoints>=aa() & currPoints<=bb()], bb(), aa()),
                 c(currCdf[currPoints>=aa() & currPoints<=bb()], 
  currCdf[currPoints==min(currPoints)],currCdf[currPoints==min(currPoints)]),
                 col="cyan",
                 density=10,
                 angle=90)
       } 
       )
 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the F distribution, I think you misnamed the arguments of the `df()` function. Try:

```r
numericInput("df1","F1: ", value = 1),
numericInput("df2","F2: ", value = 1)
```